# fix trivial/inexplicable git conflicts without merging

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

In a pull request preview on bitbucket, I have some trivial conflicts showing up, like this one, which has a blank line in the source and a blank line in the destination, but git considers it a conflict

```
+<<<<<<< destination:fdgdfdf35245b453kjb4k63k454

+=======
+        
+>>>>>>> source:34235hj3235g2kighbhjgk4jh25
```

Now, of course I can run `git merge master` within the development branch to create the lines above, fix the 'conflict' and push to the remote. But this will mean the branch is merged into master - I'd like it to remain a separate branch. Is this possible? Why does git consider the above to be a conflict anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom part of the diff contains whitespace and the top one does not.

An empty line can still be included in a change and if both of you changed this line, one with whitespaces one without, then you create a conflict.

Comment: when I view the source and destination files side-by-side, both just have one space between the neighboring lines of code (start of a function and a variable)

Comment: @CosmicDM What tool do you use to view them? On the code you pasted, on line 4, I can see a plus `+` followed by eight (8) whitespaces, where would they be coming from?

Comment: using bitbucket pull request preview, and same with git merge, the 8 whitespace will be from the automatic increment of the IDE

Comment: So bitbucket preview does show you the whitespaces. But you say that when you "view the source and destination files side-by-side" you don't see the whitespaces. What are you using to view side by side? Sometimes you have to doubt that the advanced tools you are using are showing you the real content of the file and go to simpler tools to see the details.

Comment: using bitbucket to view it side-by-side, all I see there is one vertical space in each file - it must be to do with the whitespaces

Comment: Ok so you know that bitbucket's preview is not reliable either. But where did you copy the diff that you added in your question from then?